# How to reuse AsyncTask that is injected by Dagger2?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, kotlin, dagger-2

In it's `onStart` method the fragment calls the presenter to fetch weather data.
The presenter starts an `AsyncTask` which fetches the data, returns it to the presenter and gets displayed in the fragment. 
The problem is, if I open the fragment(and fetch data), switch to another activity and then return to the fragment I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:605)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:560)
at com.dev.weather.forecast.ForecastPresenter.fetchWeather(ForecastPresenter.kt:20)
at com.dev.weather.forecast.ForecastFragment.refreshWeather(ForecastFragment.kt:83)
at com.dev.weather.forecast.ForecastFragment.onStart(ForecastFragment.kt:105)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2287)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1458)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3227)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3186)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:203)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:582)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6959)
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:7075)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3768)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3832) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I didn't have this problem before switching to dagger but now that dagger only creates one instance of the `AsyncTask` I don't know how to fix it.

I hope somebody can help me!

**Fragment:**

```
@ActivityScoped
class ForecastFragment @Inject constructor(): DaggerFragment(), ForecastContract.View {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: ForecastContract.Presenter

    override fun refreshWeather() {
        ...
        presenter.fetchWeather(location, unitType)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        refreshWeather()
    }
}
```

**Presenter:**

```
@ActivityScoped
class ForecastPresenter @Inject constructor() : ForecastContract.Presenter, FetchWeatherTask.AsyncResponse {

    @Inject
    lateinit var fetchWeatherTask: FetchWeatherTask

    override fun fetchWeather(location: String, unitType: String) {
        fetchWeatherTask.execute(location, unitType)
    }
    ...
}
```

**AsyncTask:**

```
class FetchWeatherTask @Inject constructor(private var client: OkHttpClient): AsyncTask<String, Void, MutableList<String>>() {
    ...
    override fun onPostExecute(result: MutableList<String>) {
        returnWeather()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AsyncTask` is tied to your `ForecastFragment` lifecycle. As long as your fragment lives, you will have the same instance of `fetchWeatherTask`.

You should not inject your task. Instead, create a new one every time you need it.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned you can't reuse an AsyncTask, so you should not inject it directly.

What you can do instead is inject a `Provider<FetchWeatherTask>`, which will create a new task every time you call `provider.get()`—as long as you don't scope it, in which case you'd always get the same object.